# (How) Can I use 'wild cards' on the left hand side of an array argument?

Tags: wp-query

I've spent all day trying to work out how to do this, and have only advanced a little - and that's mainly in finding methods that DON'T work. Am hoping someone knows something or can see something that I'm missing!

I have two custom post types: *Episode* and *Snippets*. *Episode* holds some info itself but also the display then builds itself using *Snippets*. I achieve this by both the *Episode* and all of the *Snippets* having the same title. So when I view an *Episode* part of the process is that it looks at all *Snippets* and displays those which have the same title. Each associated *snippet* has the same slug as the *Episode* plus a unique identifying suffix - e.g. '-1', '-2', '-3', etc.

I now need to query the database to find out if an *Episode* has a particular type of *Snippet* associated with it. This SHOULD be easy if 'page_title' was a valid entry in $args but it seems that it isn't. (It took me a sizeable chunk of today to realise that!)

The first six characters of the *Snippet* slug are the same as the *Episode* slug. But doesn't this mean I need to use a wildcard on the left-hand side of the $arg line? In words, "The first six characters of the slug => *Episode*_slug".

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

(I don't think it will be particularly helpful but you can see an example of how the two post types work together [here](http://s-t-u-f-f.net//newsquiz/s83e09/).)

Comment: why not instead come up with a more sane way to relate snippets to episodes? like store the episode ID in a snippet custom field.

Comment: or use a custom (non-hierarchical?) taxonomy to link them together?

Comment: @milo Kneejerk reaction was '... because ...' but the more I think about it, the more that idea has merit. I've got oodles of snippets for one show but in the long term it would address other issues like how long it can take to compile a page. I've got another show without many snippets yet which works the same way, so perhaps I  can implement a solution using your suggestion to check it does what I need and is easy to use, then apply it to the other if successful. Thanks for making me look at it differently! :-)

Comment: @birgire Sometimes things that strike one person as immediately obvious bypass another entirely. Thanks for making me rethink! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments to the question that there is probably a better way to associate your post types, however, the question is interesting in a "code golf" sort of way :)

> I now need to query the database to find out if an Episode has a
>   particular type of Snippet associated with it. This SHOULD be easy if
>   'page_title' was a valid entry in $args but it seems that it isn't.
>   (It took me a sizeable chunk of today to realise that!)

[`name` and `pagename`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) both address the `slug` but not with a wildcard, as you can see if you try this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'book',
  'name' => 'test',
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($q->request);
```

The easiest way to accomplish that wildcard trick is with a filter on `posts_where`:

```
function wildcard_post_slug($where) {
  remove_filter('posts_where','wildcard_post_slug');
  global $wpdb;
  return $where.' AND '.$wpdb->posts.'.post_name LIKE "Episode_%"';
}
add_filter('posts_where','wildcard_post_slug');
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'book',
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($q->request);
```

Comment: Thanks for these. The first has already moved me on further than I've got all day! Brilliant. So easy ... when you know how! Struggling a little to get at the results of the query, but I'm pretty sure they're there. The var_dump shows the query itself is spot on. I think I'm now suffering from thinking about what the others suggested. It makes perfect sense, should be easier than I thought in the past now I understand things a little better, and has loads of pluses. So I'm possibly not giving your solutions quite the concentration they deserve. But thanks. Hopefully I've learned.

Comment: Please understand, I do think that a custom field or a taxonomy is a better way to do this than hacking the post title or slug. You *should* be thinking hard about those solutions.